# Can I take a leather travel journal to usa from uk?

Tags: usa, uk, air-travel, international-travel, cbp

I bought it in England from ethnic store it was made in India and the cover is leather. That’s an animal product but I can’t see it listed on prohibited item only skin and I assume skin is the raw kind? Would they take away my journal it has all my scrap book concert photos in and old tickets.

Comment: Will they take away your leather shoes, belts and bags? This [Prohibited and Restricted Items](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/know-before-you-go/prohibited-and-restricted-items) page talks about untanned animal hide drums.